# Как создать куки только для администратора в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Как создать куки только для администратора в Wordpress?

Пробовал такой код:

```
function cookie_admin() {
    if (current_user_can('admin')) {
        if (empty($_COOKIE['disable_cache'])) {
            setcookie('disable_cache', 1);
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'cookie_admin');
```

Но в консоли Chrome видно, что файл куки не создался. Как исправить?

Comment: Если не секрет, то скажите, плз, а цель данного решения какова?

Answer (score 0):

Нет такого права 'admin'. См. [документацию на русском](https://wp-kama.ru/function/current_user_can). Для проверки, что пользователь является администратором, используется обычно `manage_options`:

```
    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
```